# Union Find algorithm in Python

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to implement Union Find algorithm in python and I don't understand what's wrong with my code as everything seems to be in the right place.

Please help in this regard. Below is my code

```
class UnionFind:
    def __init__(self,v):
        self.parent = [-1 for i in range(v)]
        self.lis=[]

    def addEdge(self,i,j):
        self.lis.append([i,j])

    def findParent(self,i):
        if self.parent[i] == -1:
            return i
        else :
            self.findParent(self.parent[i])

    def union(self,i,j):
        self.parent[i]=j

    def printResult(self):
        print self.lis

    def isBool(self):
        for lisIter in self.lis:
            x=self.findParent(lisIter[0])
            y=self.findParent(lisIter[1])
            if(x==y):
                return True
            self.union(x,y)
        return False


uf = UnionFind(3)
uf.addEdge(0,1)
uf.addEdge(1,2)
uf.addEdge(2,0)
if uf.isBool():
    print "The graph is cyclic"
else:
    print "The graph is not cyclic"
```

Comment: 'I don't understand what's wrong with my code', I assume "The graph is not cyclic" is being printed when running this script ?

Comment: @smoggers Yes..exactly. But it is cyclic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got that little logic which I missed in the my code. I need to add the return statement in the else block of findParent method or else the returned value will be discarded and a none value will get returned. Uff!

```
def findParent(self,i):
        if self.parent[i] == -1:
            return i
        else :
            return self.findParent(self.parent[i])
```